# When flying within Japan, is the zairyu card enough? Do I need my passport too?

Tags: passport, japan

Long-time foreigners in Japan walk around with their small zairyu card ("*gaijin card*") rather than having to carry their bulky passport.

But when taking the plane within Japan (for instance Sapporo-Naha), is the zairyu card enough?
Or can I be prevented from flying if I don't have my passport too?

Comment: In fact you are *required* to carry your *residence card* if you have one; a passport is not acceptable as a substitute.

Answer (score 11):

**Domestic flights in Japan do not require ID of any kind**, there are no (regular) ID checks at check-in or on the plane.

However, Japanese law requires you to carry your zairyu card at all times, whether flying on a plane or not.

Answer (score 5):

The card is sufficient.  I've flown intra-Japan many times, and never brought along my passport.

Comment: I have never been asked for my card either, for that matter, but in any case you are required to have it with you anyway... (And ditto with my passport when I was a tourist.)